# Modification of a standard cannon to project water instead of iron ball?

Tags: internal-consistency, technology, warfare

Cannonballs may be a thing of human warfare past, but it is not difficult to imagine the sense of dread at seeing a 40-pound metal projectile headed toward your ship, unable to tell for a few agonizing moments whether it will find a deadly mark.

It takes considerable might to launch a cannonball, heralded by the fact that such events are typically noisy and violent. But what is less intuitive is that at the instant a projectile leaves the device that powers its launch, the only force acting on it from that moment on, if air resistance is neglected, is Earth's gravity (assuming Earth is where this event is being staged).

This means that you can treat a projectile-motion cannon problem as two separate problems, one for constant-velocity horizontal motion imparted by the launch, and one for constant-acceleration vertical motion owing to both the object's initial upward motion (if any) and the results of gravity acting on the cannonball. The solution is found by adding these together as vector sums.

Specifically, in addition to gravity, what determines the path of a cannonball are its launch angle θ and launch (initial) speed v0.

The Equations of Cannonball Motion

The initial velocity must be separated into horizontal (v0x) and vertical (v0y) components for solving; you can obtain these from v0x = v0(cos θ) and v0y = v0(sin θ).

For horizontal motion, you have vx(t) = v0x, which can be assumed to not diminish until the object strikes something (recall there is no friction in this idealized setting). The horizontal distance traveled as a function of time t is simply x(t) = v0xt.

For vertical motion, you have vy(t) = v0y – gt, where g = 9.8 m/s2, and y(t) = v0yt – (1/2)gt2. This shows that as the effects of gravity prevail, the vertical speed increases in the negative (downward) direction.

Water cannon

A device that shoots a high-velocity stream of water. Typically, a water cannon can deliver a large volume of water, often over dozens of meters. They are used in firefighting, large vehicle washing, riot control, and mining.

That said, there is no mention of a prehistoric use of water cannons, and thus, what is the possibility of employing the physics of a cannon to that of a water cannon?

Will a water cannon require less of more black powder, how will the water be pressurized enough (150bc period tech) for long range projection?

Also, how feasible is a water cannon for ancient (aforementioned time period) mining, provided that a general cannon can be manipulated l in this manner?

Comment: Um, have you just copied and pasted a big slab of wikipedia into your question? I'm not sure what the cannonball motion equations contribute.

Comment: You wouldn't use a particle model to describe a constant stream of water. Nor would you use black powder. [Fire siphons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_fire) were available to the Greeks and Romans, so no reason why the water equivalent couldn't be possible

Comment: Trying to launch ... a ball of water ... with black powder? I think at best you'd get a lot of steam in the vicinity of the canon.

Comment: why do you think water doesn't follow just gravity after being launched?

Comment: @BMFForMonica a cannon wouldn't really heat up the water very much, and it would fire a big blob of water. I'm not sure the pressure is enough to get it to go far. I'd have said 30m, tops, though maybe I'm being overly pessimistic.

Comment: @StarfishPrime I'll admit I know nothing about cannons, but I'd expect steam, mist, and spatter, rather than coherent blobs of water.

Comment: @BMFForMonica the blob will be ablated continuously as it travels through the air, but from some probably ill-advised experimentation with air guns with water-filled barrels it can be possible to generate short, high-speed jets. It'd need a bit of experimentation with water volumes and wadding, but I'm sure you'd manage something. I'm not quite sure _why_ you'd do it, of course.

Comment: 'Um, have you just copied and pasted a big slab of wikipedia into your question?'  @StarfishPrime, guilty as charged. I know nothing about the mechanism of a cannon, but I thought it would be interesting to see whether water could replace the standard cannonball. Clearly not possible.

Comment: We really like people to quote their sources. Copying and pasting text without references is not exactly something we encourage.

Comment: @L. Dutch-ReinstateMonica, got it. I normally don't do that, as I am from a microbiology discipline. I apologize again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There appears to be some conflict in your question concerning the technology and the age in which it is deployed. Black power would not have been available in 150BC.

The problem with water is that it is a liquid and subject to extreme acceleration forces and high air resistance it tends to break up into a spray of droplets. That’s why a Water cannon has a very limited range several orders of magnitude shorter than modern firearms.

So truly long range water cannon are not really practical today and certainly would not have been feasible in 150BC regardless of the existence of black powder.

The problem might be slightly eased if ice was used instead of water but serious difficulties would remain.

It is conceivable that some form of water jet might just have been used for mining in ancient times, but such a jet would have been far removed from a Water cannon and might be better compared to a conventional hosepipe fed by gravity and used to wash out very soft materials such as clay.

Comment: Old-school mining with water involved building at dam at the top of a hill, filling it up, and then letting it go to wash all the overburden away. The Romans did that, I believe.

Comment: Yes they used water in various ways for mining anf refining, but nothing even remotely like a water cannon...

Comment: It isn't quite obvious to me when _anyone_ would have had a thing like a water cannon. Sounds pretty industrial age to me, to be honest.

Comment: Yes, of course, that what I get when I use equations of cannonball motion developed in the 1800s to try and sound smart. Worst of all, I tried to force it into 150bc time period. I apologize to everyone who has read and anyone who has to read the question.